# Equivalent definition of continuity

Tags: general-topology, analysis

So, I have these two definitions of continuity:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces, with metrics $d_{X}$ and $d_{Y},$  respectively,

(D1) We sat that a function $f : X \to Y$ is continous at the point $x_{0}$ of $X$ if for each open set $V$ of $Y$ containing $f(x_{0}),$ there is an open set $U$ of $X$ containing $x_{0}$ such that $f(U) \subset V.$

(D2)We sat that a function $f : X \to Y$ is continous at $X$ if for each open set $V$ of $Y$  $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X.$

What I'm trying to show is that they are equivalent:

$$ (D1) \Longleftrightarrow (D2) $$

Let me show you the first implication $(\Rightarrow)$

Let $x \in X,$ let me show that $ \exists V $ such that $B_{X}(x,r) \subset f^{-1}(V).$

Since $f$ is continous in $X$ then exists an open set $U \subset X$ such that $f(U) \subset V$ and $x \in U.$

Since $U$ is open, then exists an open ball $B_{X} (x,r) \subseteq U.$

If we chose any $x^{\prime} \in B_{X}(x,r)$ then $f(x^{\prime} ) \in V$ then it's clear that $B_{X}(x,r) \subseteq f^{-1}(V), $ then $f^{-1}(V)$ is an open set.

(If you have suggestions to get this part better I'll really appreciate it)

Now, I'm having some issues to finish the second part.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Let $V \subseteq Y,$ I want to show that $\exists U \subseteq X$ such that $f(U) \subseteq V.$

Since $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$ then exists $B_{X}(x,r) \subseteq U \subseteq X.$

And I don´t now how to follow the idea here. I know that $f^{-1}(V)=\left\{x|f(x) \in V \right\}$ I'm tempted to say that $B_{X}(x,r)$ is the same $f^{-1}(V)$ and that $f^{-1}(V) \subseteq U = f(f^{-1}(V)) \subseteq f(U) $ then $V \subseteq f(U).$

But I really don't know it that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you essentially have the right idea for the $(\impliedby)$ direction of the proof, but I don't think you need to introduce an open ball.

Given $x_0$ in $X$ and any open set $V \subset Y$ containing $f(x_0)$, we have by assumption that $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$. You can just let $U =  f^{-1}(V)$ and clearly $x \in f^{-1}(V)$. Additionally,  $f(U) = f\left(f^{-1}(V)\right) = V$. Since the sets are equal, we can trivially write $f(U) \subseteq V$.

Comment: I guess I lost the path trying to introduce the open ball. Now I understand where to take the open set U. Thank you.

Comment: @HelaHelheim no problem :) Sometimes the right move seems too easy to be real!